# Multi pane layout Android example project

Tags: android, sample

I've been reading about multi pane layout implementation for android and although the subject is well explained on the web, I can't manage to get good results.
It just turns out ugly.

I'm trying to find an example project that implement this and looks like the example here:
http://www.androiddocs.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html
(Or even this example exactly if you know where to get it).

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read about framgents. It can help you https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I already read pretty much everything regarding this subject (including fragments). Still, the outcome is not satisfying...

Comment: So, what do you want? What do can't understand?